# How can I pass string from HTML file to view in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new in django and i have this input in HTML,and i nedd to get the string typed from the user and send for my views.py:

```
        <form id="username_exists_form" method='GET'>
            Name: <input type="username" name="username" />
            <button type='submit'> Check </button>           
        </form>
```

That's my view.py, i nedd the string replace "username":

````
    template_name = 'Exames.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ShowExames, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        exames = Examlabs.objects.filter(id_atendimento = username)
        context.update({'exames': exames})
        return context
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Examlabs.objects.all()```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should search for some tutorials on "Django Forms" on the web.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a UserForm

`myapp/forms.py`

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
   user = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Inside the `view.py`

```
from myapp.forms import UserFrom

def user_form(request):   
   if request.method == "POST":
      # Get the posted form
      my_user_form = UserFrom(request.POST)
      
      if my_user_form.is_valid():
         # do anything here
         username = my_user_form.cleaned_data['username']
   else:
      my_user_form = UserFrom()
        
   return render(request, 'mypage.html', {"username" : username})
```

Inside `mypage.html`

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form name = "form" action = "{% url "myapp.views.user_form" %}" 
         method = "POST" >{% csrf_token %}
               <input type = "text" name = "username" />
               <button type = "submit" value = "Submit" ></button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is helpful please upvote my solution.

Comment: Doing in that way is possible to make a filter in exame? In the code there's already in my view.