# getting input value on button click in django

Tags: django, view, django-templates

i'm trying to get the input value on button click

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   if request.POST['fah']:
```

this is getting me False when page is loaded and if i click on button, it's not changing

how can i write something like js addEventListener in django?

**my button**

```
<button type="button" class="bbtn" name="fah" id="fah" value="fah">Convert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of a button is not submitted if the button does not have role submit. You can include a hidden field that contains your value or pass the value as a URL query string.

Comment: Take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755179/how-can-i-pass-string-from-html-file-to-view-in-django/69755323#69755323